# Victory point counting and Sanguinary Priests

Tags: warhammer-40k

Up to 3 Sanguinary Priests (Blood Angel Codex) count as a single unit choice, but how must we count the victory points for killing them?
Do all 3 must be removed for it to count as 1 VP? Or do each causality count as a single VP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this, but I had a look around for you and found this: http://www.bolterandchainsword.com/topic/261515-sanguinary-priest-spam/

in it, Xenith states:

> Individual models are each a kill point. KP is not based upon how many
>   force org slots are taken up.
>
> Case in point being dedicated transports.
>
> Sorry

Hope this helps :)